# Como e porque getElementById não executa no carregamento da página?

Tags: front-end, dom, javascript-eventos

**Business problem:** Criarei um sistema que rodará em uma plataforma sem servidor. Pode ser uma interface de área de administração local (um client para um serviço), ou um aplicativo Mobile. A aplicação carregará conteúdo dinamicamente, para facilitar atualização e manutenção, usando apenas tecnologia ao lado do cliente (CSS e javascript). Motivos não vem ao caso para não poluir o tópico.

**Technical problem:** O objeto document.write() tem má fama de sobrescrever o documento, e construir todo documento com a função write é muito complicado. Então geralmente escolhemos atualizar conteúdo pelo getElementById, apesar de muita gente recomendar uso de AJAX ou Jquery que  por certos motivos não funcionam fora do servidor, para o escopo desse projeto. No entanto, o getElementById não carrega sem a chamada de uma função no código abaixo, ou mesmo chamada onload no Body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="recebeProduto1"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

        getElementById("recebeProduto1").innerHTML = "teste";

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Pergunta: Como e porque getElementById não executa no carregamento da página?**

ou

**Quais alternativas para carregar conteúdo dinâmicamente usando tecnologia Client-Side?**

Comment: Cara, na verdade é `document.getElementById`....

Comment: a ideia é explanar o porque disso para evitar equívocos com objeto javascript, mas sim! Está correto!

Comment: O método `getElementById` pertence ao objeto/classe `document`, por isso, não tem como acessar ele diretamente, só através do `document`.

Comment: No entanto, quando chamamos através de uma função, ele disponibiliza o conteúdo. Porque isso?

Comment: Quando é utilizado dentro de uma função, o `getElementById` está dentro do contexto do `document`, porém, é sempre recomendado utilizar o `document`, assim evitando erros como por exemplo "função não encontrada".

Comment: Tenho aqui os links relacionados a este tipo de problema.
Quer criar uma resposta formal para eu marcar como melhor resposta?
https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html (getElementById introduced in DOM Level 2)

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp

Comment: Não, ta tranquilo. O importante é você ter entendido.

Answer (score 4):

mude seu código para `document.getElementById("recebeProduto1")` pois o `getElementById` é um método do objeto `document`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="recebeProduto1"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

        document.getElementById("recebeProduto1").innerHTML = "teste";

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```